# Save twitter search result to JSON file

Tags: ruby, twitter

I am using twitter ruby gem to fetch twitter search result. The example code from Github extracts the information from search result.I am wondering how to save the search result, which is JSON i think, to a separate JSON file.
Here is part of the example code:

```
results = @search.perform("$aaa", 1000)
aFile = File.new("data.txt", "w")
results.map do |status|
myStr="#{status.from_user}: #{status.text}  #{status.created_at}"
aFile.write(myStr)
aFile.write("\n")
end
```

Is there any way to save all the search result to a separate JSON file instead of writing strings to a file?
       Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pro tip: use [`File.open` with a block](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-open) instead of `File.new` and manual closing. This makes closing of the file deterministic and exception-safe.

Comment: `JSON` is just a way that data is formatted. Ultimately, it is just one long string. You can save the data to file, the same way you'd save other text to a file. You don't need to save it with any special file extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save to a file all you need to do is open the file, write it it, then close it:

```
File.open("myFileName.txt", "a") do |mFile|
    mFile.syswrite("Your content here")
    mFile.close
end
```

When you use `open` you will create the file if it doesn't exist.

One thing to be aware of is that there are different ways to open file, of which will determine where the program writes to. The `"a"` indicates that it will append everything you write to the file, to the end of the current content.

Here is some of the options:

```
r   Read-only mode. The file pointer is placed at the beginning of the file. This is the default mode.
r+  Read-write mode. The file pointer will be at the beginning of the file.
w   Write-only mode. Overwrites the file if the file exists. If the file does not exist, creates a new file for writing.
w+  Read-write mode. Overwrites the existing file if the file exists. If the file does not exist, creates a new file for reading and writing.
a   Write-only mode. The file pointer is at the end of the file if the file exists. That is, the file is in the append mode. If the file does not exist, it creates a new file for writing.
a+  Read and write mode. The file pointer is at the end of the file if the file exists. The file opens in the append mode. If the file does not exist, it creates a new file for reading and writing.
```

So in your case, you would want to pull out the data you want to save, then write it to a file as I have shown. You can also specify file paths by doing:

```
File.open("/the/path/to/yourfile/myFileName.txt", "a") do |mFile|
    mFile.syswrite("Your content here")
    mFile.close
end
```

Another thing to be aware of is that `open` does not create directories, so you will either need to create directories yourself, or you can do it with your program. Here is a link that is helpful for file input/output:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_input_output.htm